# display image with jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i want to display image at browser with help of given code

images.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ pageimport="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory,javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,org.w3c.dom.*"
%>
<html>
<body><center><table border="2">
<%DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse("\\file1.XML");
NodeList pic1= doc.getElementsByTagName("pic1");
NodeList pic2= doc.getElementsByTagName("pic2");
%>


 <tr><td>
 <img  border="2" src=<%= pic1.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %> width="137" height="140"></td>
<td>
 <img  border="2" src=<%= pic2.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %> width="137"  height="140">
</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <images>
 <pic1>BULDHANA.jpg</pic1>
 <pic2>BULDHANA.jpg</pic2>

 </images>
```

but it is not display images. Where is the problem. How can i resolve it???

Comment: How does the *generated* HTML look like? Are the image paths correct?

Comment: You have not posted the contents of `file1.xml`. Did you try wrapping the img src with double quotes?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <images>
 <pic1>BULDHANA.jpg</pic1>
 <pic2>BULDHANA.jpg</pic2>
 
 </images>
this is the code for file1.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check HTML rendered on browser check for `img` tag whats its `src` attribute?? , and what it should be ??

**Update:**

Your dir structure should be like this

jsp file at

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\SampleApp\1.jsp
```

image file at

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\SampleApp\images\1.jpg
```

in my browser address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/1.jsp
```

HTML code

```
<img src="images/1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: @Felix It is answer to her question actually.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - org.life.java: Not really. You are *asking* two questions yourself. Now if the OP founds out that the paths are incorrect, what should he do? You are just telling him what he should do to find out what could be wrong, but not how to solve the problem (displaying images).

Comment: i am placed file1.xml inside bin and images inside webapps\jsp-examples. It is not showing images.Where i have to place images???

Comment: @neha soni: First you have to show us how the *generated* HTML looks like. Are the image sources correct?

Comment: just add `<img  border="2" src=/images/<%= pic2.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %>`

Comment: @Felix, just to correct that ,thats what she is asking for. this answer will give her a final clue that what is the problem actually

Comment: goto your web browser , right click on the page ,  click view page source , search for `img` tag and tell us what is there ?

Comment: this is the code shown at web browser
<html>
<body><center><table border="2">


 <tr><td>
 <img border="2" src=/images/BULDHANA.jpg
  width="137" height="140"></td>
<td>
 <img border="2" src=/images/BULDHANA.jpg
  width="137"  height="140">
</td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 </center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ya my dir structure is like that tomcat5.5.9\webapps\jsp-examples\images1.jsp, tomcat5.5.9\webapps\jsp-examples\images\BULDHANA.jpg, and my file1.xml is inside tomcat5.5.9\bin\file1.xml.

Comment: how can i access images placed in "webapps/jsp-examples/images" folder via my jsp page???

Comment: make it `images/BULDHANA.jpg` note leading slash is not there

Comment: i hav tried src=<%= "images/BULDHANA.jpg" %> but it is not displaying any image.

Comment: if there is any error in code or in dir structure thn let me knw.

Comment: there is error for sure. if you can elaborate your dir structure **clearly** then I can point it out

Comment: i hav placed my jsp file at "C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\Webapps\jsp-examples\images1.jsp" and image "BULDHANA.jpg" at "..\Webapps\jsp-examples\images\BULDHANA.jpg" and file1.xml at "tomcat5.5.9\bin" folder

Comment: Neha, I have updated again, This will be my last update. there is no huge issue.

Comment: i hav done the same but its not displaying images... I m tired of this problem but it is not solving..

Comment: there must be some browser issue then..try checking with some other browser

Comment: there is a case dat my program is running for a image "Logo.jpg" but it is not running for any other image. Why is it doing so???

Comment: where this file is located ? and what HTML is being generated for this working case?

Comment: Same code same file location. but still the code is working for a single image not for others. And also my tomcat is behaving so unusual that once i save a file in  Webapps/jsp-examples folder. Many times it was the case that it doesnt show me that file there..

Comment: should i install tomcat again??? Is it the problem of tomcat??? or There is some other issue behind it??

Comment: It should not happen, give it a shot by reinstalling